# How to generate a GIF thumbnail from a video without saving individual frames to disk?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I have a Node.js script that uses fluent-FFmpeg to generate a GIF thumbnail from a video for the first 4 seconds. Currently, the script saves individual frames as PNG images to disk, and then reads them back in to generate the GIF. However, this creates a lot of unnecessary I/O.

Is there a way to modify the script to generate the GIF directly from the video frames, without saving them to disk first? Ideally, I would like to do this while still using FFmpeg for the processing.

Here's the current code for generating the frames and the GIF:

```
function generateFrames(videoUrl) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ffmpeg(videoUrl)
      .setStartTime(0) // start at 0 seconds
      .setDuration(4) // cut 4 seconds
      .videoFilters('scale=if(gte(iw\\,ih)\\,min(600\\,iw)\\,-2):if(lt(iw\\,ih)\\,min(600\\,ih)\\,-2)')
      .fps(4)
      .output('output/img%04d.png') // output file pattern with %04d indicating a sequence number with four digits
      .on('end', () => {
        console.log('GIF generated successfully!');
        resolve()
      })
      .on('error', (err) => {
        console.log('Error generating GIF: ' + err.message);
        reject()
      })
      .run();
  });
}

function generateGif() {
  const inputPattern = 'output/img%04d.png';
  const outputFilename = 'output/output2.gif';

  ffmpeg(inputPattern)
    .inputFPS(9)
    .output(outputFilename)
    .on('error', (err) => {
      console.log('Error generating GIF: ' + err.message);
    })
    .run();
}


execute = async () => {
  await generateFrames('video.mp4')
  generateGif()
}

execute()
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: try to replace `.output('output/img%04d.png')` with `.output('output/out.gif')`

Comment: your suggestion works, but it generate a gif with 4 fps and 4 seconds duration, this is why I used the second function to generate a thumbnail with 16/9 seconds ~ 2sec and 9 fps

Comment: try to change `.videoFilters(...` to `scale=600:600:force_original_aspect_ratio=1:flags=lanczos,setsar=1,setpts=PTS/16*9,fps=9,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse=new=1:dither=bayer`